# How to add custom xcframework to xcode custom project template?

Tags: ios, xcode, templates

I am trying to create custom xcode project template for the project. How to add custom framework to the xcode project template on TemplateInfo.plist file?

Answer (score 0):

### Adding a non Apple Framework to your Xcode Project Template

1. Copy framework to the root of your xctemplate folder.
2. Open TemplateInfo.plist
3. In the Nodes Key, add new line, then enter in the desired path of where to place framework

   ```
   ../MyTest.xcframework
   ```
4. In the Definitions Key Area, add the newly created node item.
5. Set the sub-properties of the new Definition entry as follows:

   ```
   Concrete (Boolean) = 0,
   FileType (String) = Framework (THIS IS IMPORTANT)
   Path (String) = Path to framework in the xctemplate folder
   ```

### Additional Advice

Do not use the Build Phases Key or the Frameworks Key in Targets. This will only recognize apple framework names. Also the Frameworks Key doesn't support XCFramework type. I encourage you to build all custom frameworks as XCFramework for the new Xcode build system.

*I do not know how to automatically add the custom framework to the default Frameworks Group once the Xcode Project is made*. I normally just drag them to that group if desired, be sure if you do that your custom framework was saved to ($SRCROOT) without subfolders. Or else you will need to relink the file path reference.

!!BE SURE TO CHECK YOUR SYMLINKS INSIDE YOUR FRAMEWORK ARE CORRECT!!